# NSFetchedResultsController error: 'no object at index in section at index 0'

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableView which populate it cells with a NSFetchedResultsController based on CoreData attribute `isForConverter` which is Bool and should be true to be displayed. `isForConverter` state sets in another ViewController.
When I want to delete some cells from the UITableView and after access cells which wasn't deleted I receive the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'no object at index 5 in section at index 0'
```

There is a GIF with the problem: https://cln.sh/M1aI9Z

My code for deleting cells. I don't need to delete it from database, just change it `isForConverter` from true to false:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let currency = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        currency.isForConverter = false
        coreDataManager.save()
    }
}
```

NSFetchedResultsController Setup and delegates:

```
func setupFetchedResultsController() {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isForConverter == YES")
    fetchedResultsController = coreDataManager.createCurrencyFetchedResultsController(with: predicate)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    try? fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }
    case .move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)
        }
    case .delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }
    case .insert:
        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .none)
        }
    default:
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

I noticed that if I just add `tableView.reloadData()` to:

> tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle:
> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Then everything works good. But deletion animation is really fast and antsy. Also according to docs I should not use `tableView.reloadData()` with NSFetchedResultsController...

How to fix that behaviour?

**UPDATE:**

It seems I found out what the reason of that crash was. This is what my print() tryings gave: [SCREENSHOT](https://cln.sh/jpB5tG).
What is a pickedCurrency: this is a global variable of custom type Currency which I created to receive its attribute currentValue (Double, 87.88). I need that value only from the picked to edit cell. After I use that value for calculation at cellForRowAt() and result of the calculation fills all other cells which is not in the edit mode now.

I define pickedCurrency in textFieldDidBeginEditing() because there I receive the exact row of Currency I picked to edit:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    pickedCurrency = fetchedResultsController.object(at: IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0))
    numberFromTextField = 0
    textField.textColor = UIColor(named: "BlueColor")
    textField.placeholder = "0"
    textField.text = ""
}
```

And then use it's value in cellForRowAt to calculate all other cells values based on pickedCell value and number I put in a textField of activeCell:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "converterCell", for: indexPath) as! ConverterTableViewCell
    
    let currency = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    cell.flag.image = currencyManager.showCurrencyFlag(currency.shortName ?? "notFound")
    cell.shortName.text = currency.shortName
    cell.fullName.text = currency.fullName
    cell.numberTextField.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.numberTextField.delegate = self
    
    if let number = numberFromTextField, let pickedCurrency = pickedCurrency {
        cell.numberTextField.text = currencyManager.performCalculation(with: number, pickedCurrency, currency)
    }
    return cell
}
```

It seems when I delete a lot of cells and then click on random cell to edit it's not updates its `IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0)`...

Maybe there is a way to receive Currency object I picked for editing in `cellForRowAt()`?

Comment: You are right, it is not recommended to use `tableView.reloadData` with Fetched results controller. I am wondering if your default case in switch might be the cause of the issue. So in default case, instead of `tableView.reloadData()`, can you just remove this and add `return` - do you still see this issue ? Because looking at other things, it seems like you have set things up properly.

Comment: @ShawnFrank Hei Shawn, thank you. Tried to add return and error still remains. Also I found out if I call reloadData() with DispathQueue.AsyncAfter .now() + 0.5 then animation remains  smooth... To clarify: I receive the error only after straight deletion of big amount of cells (> than 10), if I delete 1-2 cells then no error, no need to call reloadData()...

Comment: please can you add the code you wrote for number of sections and number of rows ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank I have only 1 section so I have the code only for number of rows (added to initial post at the end)

Comment: This also looks fine to me, maybe it can just be safer instead of using `!` but I do not think that is your issue ... strange .. Seems like you have set up as per documentation. Maybe something in `cell for row at indexPath` - how do you access `currency` object there ? Maybe you can add some snippet of that

Comment: @ShawnFrank no problem, added all code for my cellForRow

Comment: Hmm .. seems ok. On first view I cannot see anything wrong .. maybe I will try to set up later and test unless you have this project on some repo. I am only thinking `case .delete:` is not running because no `deletion` actually takes place in your scenario and `case .update:` is what happens instead - maybe you can confirm this with breakpoint, it is just an observation and this should not be the reason for your crash.

Comment: Can you try one more thing, use the same Managed object to save the data. Instead of `coreDataManager.save()` which **might** not be what the FetchedResultsController is observing can you `currency.managedObjectContext.save` - you might have to put this in try catch block and might have to make so small changes with optionals.

Comment: @ShawnFrank I think I found out where the problem is. Please take a look at my post below Update. Seems everything is ok with FRC...

Comment: Ah this is the issue then - let's say you have 5 rows. Each row is given identifier as tag 0 to 4. When you remove row 2 for example, row 0 has tag 0, row 1 has tag 1 but row 2 has tag 3 because original row 2 was deleted so there is a chance that index can go out of bounds. I think we need to think of a cleaner way to identify each textfield in each row. Fastest way is to reload the table again so that the tag and rows will be synchronized again. More complex way would be to think of another way to identify cells uniquely or update tags to be correct.

Comment: @ShawnFrank yes, and this is why when I call tableView.reloadData() in 'commit editingStyle .delete' case everything is work - because tags reload too. Can you help me how to get rid of tags in the case of pickedCurrency to identify which row am I editing now? As I understood, just reload tableView not an option coz I use FRC... If you need some additional info to provide - let me know. I would be very grateful!

Comment: Let me think about it a bit .. in the meantime if you also come up with something - would be nice to know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain if this will work but it seems too long for it to be a comment so give the below a try.

Initially I told you could use tag to identify a specific view which is good for quick and simple implementations but when rows get moved / deleted as we have it now, it will be very difficult to manage using tags as you have to constantly update them.

For static table views, they are fine but if your rows will change, then more sophisticated patterns like delegate / observer might be better.

Anyways, what I think can help your situation for now in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is stop using the tag to get the index path and get the indexpath from what is tapped.

I still think maybe delegate pattern is better but this might work for you:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // Get the coordinates of where we tapped in the table
    let tapLocation = textField.convert(textField.bounds.origin,
                                        to: tableView)
    
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation)
    {
        // don't use tag of textfield anymore
        pickedCurrency
            = fetchedResultsController.object(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath,
                                                            section: 0))
        
        numberFromTextField = 0
        textField.textColor = UIColor(named: "BlueColor")
        textField.placeholder = "0"
        textField.text = ""
    }
}
```

Does this help ?

Comment: Everything works great! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked @artexhibit - since this i working, maybe change logic of using tags from other areas also.

Comment: can you check that question please? it's related because this was the last place where I use tags...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71021350/uitableviews-indexpathsforvisiblerows-updates-all-cells-except-one