# UITableView's indexPathsForVisibleRows updates all cells except one

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableView which populate it cells with a NSFetchedResultsController. Also I use indexPathsForVisibleRows to update visible cells except the one I tapped and edit. But the UI updates all cells with proper calculation except one. If I scroll that tableView then that cell recalculate itself next time it becomes visible.

GIF with the problem: [CLICK](https://cln.sh/wLAtcx)

There I define the cell to edit and reload Rows for all cells except the one I am editing:

```
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let tapLocation = textField.convert(textField.bounds.origin, to: tableView)
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation) else { return }
    pickedCurrency = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    
    let visibleIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? []
    var nonActiveIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    
    for index in visibleIndexPath where index != indexPath {
        nonActiveIndexPaths.append(index)
    }
    
    tableView.reloadRows(at: nonActiveIndexPaths, with: .none)
}
```

Why the UI updates all cells except one? Can't find the reason...

Comment: Please can you add the code of `cellForRow atIndexPath` and if you are using `willShowCell atIndexPath` - I believe the problem is there. Code above updates textfields of cells that are `visible`, the cell that is not updated is not part of visible cells and so will most likely be configured when you scroll and reach `cellForRow atIndexPath`

Comment: @ShawnFrank, thanks again. I think I found a good solution after your comment. I post as an answer below. What do you think from your experience is it good or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I managed to solve my problem. The thing I understood is I should avoid using `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows` for my case since as @ShawnFrank stated it will reload only visible cells:

```
func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {

     //Code for defining an active cell (on which I clicked to edit its textField)
    let tapLocation = textField.convert(textField.bounds.origin, to: tableView)
    guard let pickedCurrencyIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation) else { return }
    pickedCurrency = fetchedResultsController.object(at: pickedCurrencyIndexPath)
    
    //Array for all IndexPaths which is not selected, i.e. not active
    var nonActiveIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    
    //Define all rows tableView has at the moment for particular section 
    //In my case it can be only 1 section which starts at 0 index
    let tableViewRows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
    for i in 0..<tableViewRows {
    //Create indexPath with the rows and section
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
    //Add all IndexPaths to previously created array, except the one that is active now
        if indexPath != pickedCurrencyIndexPath {
            nonActiveIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
        }
    }
    //Reload only rows from the array
    tableView.reloadRows(at: nonActiveIndexPaths, with: .none)
}
```